# Displaying simple html pages DJango

Tags: html, django, web

I'm currently using Django 1.5 and can't figure out how to display a simple html page. I've been reading about class based views, but am not sure this is what I want to do.

I'm trying to display a simple index.html page, but according to some examples I've seen I need to put this code in app/views.py:

```
    def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template("app/index.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render)
```

Is there a reason why my index.html page has to be associated with the app associated with my django project? For me, it seems to make more sense to have an index.html page correspond to the overall project.

More to the point, using this code in my views.py file, what do I need to put into my urls.py in order to actually index.html?

EDIT:

Structure of Django project:

```
webapp/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    manage.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        templates/
            index.html
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Comment: Reading the django tutorial would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app_name.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

Based on @Ezequiel Bertti answer, remove `app`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^index.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

Your index.html must be store inside templates folder

```
webapp/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        templates/      <---add
            index.html  <---add
    manage.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        templates/      <---remove
            index.html  <---remove
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Comment: catherine, I'm getting a syntaxerror with "name='index'" in urls.py. are you sure its not template_name or something different? thanks!

Comment: now it just gives me a templatedoesnotexist error. is there something special about the index.html file that i need to have? i just have it sitting inside my app/ right now, yet it doesn't seem to know what/where it is?

Comment: hmmm I had actually already tried that and got the same problem with it inside the "templates" directory.

Comment: erg after making all those changes i run a local server and went to localhost:8001/index.html (the port I chose) and it still gives a templatedoesnotexisterror. Thank you btw for all your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: your app urls.py codes please and it's not `localhost:8001/index.html`, it depends on your urlname

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27065/discussion-between-shawn-taylor-and-catherine)

Comment: hmmm maybe that's the problem then, i dont have a urls.py file in my app directory, only in my project directory

Answer (score 4):

You can use a GenericView of django core:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^index.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```

Comment: I just keep getting a "TemplateDoesNoteExist" error when I run things this way...

Comment: if you keep getting "TemplateDoesNoteExist" error then try by setting your project's settings.py file , update TEMPLATE -> DIRS to be your file path, you have to indicate where the templates folder is located

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have configured the path in setting.py. Probably it will resolve TemplateDoesNoteExist error.

You can place the below one in settings.py.

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(**file**))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)